# Hide out of stock WooCommerce products only on a AJAX widget with Elementor

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm trying to add a product archive widget in Elementor but in this widget specifically must hide "Out of stock" products.

I try to use the following code`s but I have not succeeded, because they doesn't work if Elementor widget is AJAX.

If the widget is not AJAX, then it`s fine (they are working).

How to modify this code`s to work with AJAX?

1). With a meta query:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'custom_products_widget_query_arg', 10, 1 );
function custom_products_widget_query_arg( $query_args ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => '!='
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

2). Or with a tax query:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_products_widget_query_args', 'custom_products_widget_query_arg', 10, 1 );
function custom_products_widget_query_arg( $query_args ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => array('outofstock'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

I found this codes from another stack question:
[Answered by @LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416092/hide-out-of-stock-woocommerce-products-only-on-a-widget-with-elementor)